# How to pass multiple Lat and Long on KML URL?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, latitude-longitude

For 1 lat and Long 
we can pass on URL like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=23.08136,72.572849&daddr=22.942071,72.379461&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

but i want to pass multiple Lat and Long on this URL.
for Example :

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=23.08136,72.572849&daddr=22.942071,72.379461&
saddr=23.052850,72.525930&daddr=22.986080,72.394280&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
```

So how we can pass multiple Lat and Long on google Map URL ?

Answer (score 0):

output=kml is not an officially documented way to get data out of Google. If you're looking to get driving directions, you should use the Google Driving Directions web service:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/